# How to convert nested if in crystal report to powerbi paginated report

Tags: powerbi, crystal-reports, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am working on below on how to convert the below report in crystal report formula to powerbi report builder. I am trying it in IIF program or SWITCH for expression

```
if not isnull({A}) then 

    if {?Q} = 0 then
        (if {B} = 1  then
            {D} / {C}
        else 
        if {B} = 2 and {C} <> 0 then
            {D} * {C}
        else 0)

    else

        (if {B} = 1  then
            {?Q} / {C}
        else 
        if {B} = 2 and {C} <> 0 then
            {?Q} * {C}
        else 0) 

else 0
```

Comment: Where do yoo want ot use it, in a DAX or mquery? Your question is to vague/generic, please try to make this a concreate problem (the problem you are working on) so we can help you.

Comment: Want it in IIF normal program

Comment: I want it in switch abnormal program

Comment: Sure we can use it in switch too

Comment: Is there any way you can provide sample data and desired output? It may not be possible to decipher what the above does just by looking at the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume that for the sake of this answer we are using the following structures:

`MyTable`

```
|-----|------|------|------|
|ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
|-----|------|------|------|
|1    | 2    | 3    | 4    |
|-----|------|------|------|
```

`QParam`

> A numeric value which is used for multiplication or division.

To make my version relatively easy, I'm going to simply make this a column calculation since it looks to be row specific.

```
CalcCol = 
   IF( 
    NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ColA])),  
    IF( SUM(QParam[QParam]) = 0, 
       IF( 'Table'[ColB] = 1, 
            'Table'[ColD] / 'Table'[ColC], 
            IF( AND('Table'[ColB] = 2, 'Table'[ColC] <> 0),
                'Table'[ColD] * 'Table'[ColC], 
                0)),
        IF( 'Table'[ColB] = 1, 
            SUM(QParam[QParam]) / 'Table'[ColC], 
            IF( AND('Table'[ColB] = 2, 'Table'[ColC] <> 0), 
               SUM(QParam[QParam]) * 'Table'[ColC],
            0))
    ), 
    0)
```

This is a valid formula within PowerBI Desktop - can't confirm the same for PowreBI Report Builder though.

A version of this using the switch function would be something like:

```
SwitchCol = 
    SWITCH (
    TRUE,
    ( NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ColA])) &&
    SUM(QParam[QParam]) = 0 && 
    'Table'[ColB] = 1 ) , 'Table'[ColD] / 'Table'[ColC],
    ( NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ColA])) &&
    SUM(QParam[QParam]) = 0 && 
    'Table'[ColB] = 2 &&
    'Table'[ColC] <> 0 ) , 'Table'[ColD] * 'Table'[ColC],        
    ( NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ColA])) &&
    SUM(QParam[QParam]) <> 0 && 
    'Table'[ColB] = 1 ) , SUM(QParam[QParam]) / 'Table'[ColC],        
    ( NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[ColA])) &&
    SUM(QParam[QParam]) <> 0 && 
    'Table'[ColB] = 2 &&
    'Table'[ColC] <> 0 ) , SUM(QParam[QParam]) * 'Table'[ColC],
    0
)
```

Up to you as to which you find more maintainable, performs best, or fails to work in report builder.